# ArcGIS Pro Enable Feature Binning

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I have a point feature layer in a `gdb` that I would like convert to `bins` via the `Enable Feature Binning` tool in `ArcGIS Pro 3`. However, I am getting the following error.

How can I create an `RDMS` to resolve this error? Or is there an alternative tool which does not require a `RDBMS` to create such a bin map?

```
002685: Feature Binning is not supported on this datasource. Enable Feature Binning is only supported against RDBMS.
```

Example Bin map from `ArcInsights` that I would like to replicate in `ArcGIS Pro`:

[image]

Comment: The error tells you that you need to use an RDBMS (enterprise) geodatabase, not a file geodatabase feature class.

Comment: What would your "fix" encompass? The error states the issue. Enhancement requests are submitted as "Ideas" in the [Esri Community](https://community.esri.com)

Comment: @Vince, I am new to `RDBMS` so I don't know how to create one? And why does the tool works with `RDMS` only?

Comment: You generally wouldn't create a new database just to use this feature. Standing up a new database takes just minutes for an experienced DBA, but it takes years to be an experienced DBA. Relational databases are geared toward GROUP BY queries, so this sort of operation is bread-and-butter for them.

Comment: @Arthur_Morgan This feature requires an Enterprise Geodatabase, because it's actually leveraging database functions, produces, and methods to create and return bin information. I was given a pretty detailed technical explanation at one point, but the particulars have long since left me.

Comment: @KHibma, thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/enable-feature-binning.htm):

> Feature binning is only supported for point and multipoint feature
> classes stored in an enterprise geodatabase, database, or cloud data
> warehouse. The data cannot be versioned or archive enabled.
>
> Supported platforms are as follows:
>
> ```
> Amazon Redshift
> IBM Db2
> Google BigQuery
> Microsoft SQL Server
> Oracle
> PostgreSQL
> SAP HANA
> Snowflake
> ```

So, you can't use the Enable Feature Binning with a file geodatabase feature class. However, you can make a (non-dynamic) bin aggregation by using [Generate Tesselation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/generatetesellation.htm) to create your bin polygons, then [Summarize Within](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/summarize-within.htm) to summarize your data. You would have to re-run Summarize Within if your source data changed.